# How to validate Google Recaptcha from server(Java) side?

Tags: java, spring, recaptcha

I have login page with working Google Recaptcha

[image: Login]

The problem is, even if I'm not pressing I'm not a robot, I can login. How to make check that the checkboxed is checked?

My java code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> login(@RequestParam String email,
                                                     HttpServletRequest request){

        String ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
        String captchaVerifyMessage = request.getParameter("g-recaptcha-response");
        captchaService.verifyRecaptcha(ip, captchaVerifyMessage);
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(captchaVerifyMessage)) {
            Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
            response.put("message", captchaVerifyMessage);
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest()
                    .body(response);
        }
        String token;
        User user = userRepository.findOneByEmail(email);
        Map<String, Object> tokenMap = new HashMap<>();
        if (user != null) {
            token = Jwts.builder().setSubject(email).claim("roles", user.getRoles()).setIssuedAt(new Date())
                    .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, "secretkey").compact();
            tokenMap.put("token", token);
            tokenMap.put("user", user);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(tokenMap, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            tokenMap.put("token", null);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(tokenMap, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }
```

My aim is to make some alert message, smth like "You need to prove that you're not a robot"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to verify it using javascript before submitting your form.

```
function checkCaptcha() {
  if (!grecaptcha.getResponse()) {
    alert("You need to prove that you're not a robot");
  } else {
    document.getElementById('yourFormId').submit();
  }
}
```

And in your `<form>` change the `<button>` type to `button` and call `checkCaptcha()` on click.

```
<button type='button' onclick='checkCaptcha()'>Login</button>
```

Because by default type is `submit`, which will cause the form to submit on press.

---

If you want to validate reCaptcha from server side take a look at the following post of mine.

- [How to validate reCAPTCHA V2 Java (Servlet)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47622506/2408342)